# Women tefillah groups

Tags: halacha, tefilla, women

What would be the halachic problems the people have with women's tefillah groups/"minyanim", where a number of women all get together to *daven* together. They do everything that men would do, except they do it *sans* men.

Women can daven, even if they are not obligated, and they can technically read from the Torah as well. Is it only that they cannot make the bracha on the Torah, and leaving that out would remove all technical issues with the whole thing? Or is there something else as well?

Comment: They're missing minyan!

Comment: Who says women aren't obligated to daven??

Comment: re "remove all technical issues": http://parsha.blogspot.co.il/2006/07/korach-minyan-this-past-shabbos_04.html

Comment: Could you please [clarify in the question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/29592/edit) what the "women's tefillah groups/'minyanim'" you refer to are and do?

Comment: @msh210 I suppose I mean when a bunch of women get together all to daven together. They do everything that men would do, except they do it sans-men.

Comment: @devirkahan Does that include Chazarat haShatz, Birkat Kohanim, Kaddish, Kedusha, being Motziah each other in Brachot, Barchu, and Haftarah?

Comment: How could they read from the Torah without a minyan?

Comment: @ezra take it out, open it, read. Seemingly the first step is just for convenience

Comment: Women davening together =/= minyan

Answer (score 2):

This is a delicate topic that mixes questions of *halacha* with *hashkafa*. The answer will also depend on the type of women's prayer group being discussed (e.g., regular service addressed below vs. one-off Simchat Torah or *bat mitsva* ceremony). I will try here to surface some of the arguments and refer the interested reader to additional sources.

In a nutshell very prominent Modern Orthodox *poskim* were opposed to women prayer groups for full services although some others allowed them in limited settings such as *Megilla* readings. One of the reasons is to allow women to participate in regular synagogue services where they also belong.

---

R Gil Student summarizes [here](https://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2004/04/womens-prayer-groups-rav-soloveitchiks.html) the position of [R Yosef Dov Soloveitchik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_B._Soloveitchik). There is debate whether R Soloveitchik's opposition was matter of strict *halakha*, of *halakhic values* or of public policy but it came from multiple directions: deviation from customs, beginning of larger-scale reform, improper motivation, inauthentic practice, distortion of Torah, *non-halakhic* agendas, heterodox practices and community divisiveness.

In a similar survey of R [Herschel Schachter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershel_Schachter)'s position ([here](https://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2004/03/womens-prayer-groups-r-hershel_30.html)), R Gil Student lists another set of drivers for his opposition to what he calls a "improper and even dangerous innovation", e.g., incomplete *mitzvot* (i.e., missing minyan and kaddish, *kedushah*, *barekhu*, repetition of the *amidah* and an official reading of the Torah), breaking from normative *halakhah*, impure motivations, lack of established custom, improper synagogue customs, imitating non-Jews.

[R Shlomo Goren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Goren) did write a responsa permitting women prayer groups (see [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/tfila/frimmer1.htm) for a summary which contradicts his arguments) but retracted it at the end of his life.

As noted in the introduction, there are more restricted settings where women prayer groups might be appropriate and *halakhically* permitted (e.g., Rs Frimer [mention](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/tfila/frimmer1.htm) R Moshe Feinstein permitting a *Megilla* reading (see also here from [R Michael Broyde](https://www.torahmusings.com/2012/10/womens-only-torah-reading/)), or the London *Beit Din* permitting *Kabalat Shabbat*, *Hallel* or a Torah reading without blessings, as long as this is done for pure motives).